# Update a regex to find SQL syntax errors

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this regular expressions to find syntax errors off of webpages (I'm a pentester for a living):

```
SQL_REGEX = %r((?-mix:SQL query error)|(?-mix:MySQL Query Error)|(?-mix:expects parameter)|(?-mix:You have an error in your SQL syntax))
```

I would like a regex that will find the error messages on a website if they have incorrectly closed SQL syntax, the one above works, but it seems to me that it's a little slower then it *could* be, any suggestions on how to make a better more reliable regex?

Comment: Why do you think it has performance issues? FYI: those pattern modifiers are not necessary. Also why a RegEx?!

Comment: @revo I don't think it does, I just think it could be better, `regex` because I'm pulling the information from the `html` of the site, and it seemed like the easiest option since I already knew what I was doing. What do you mean the modifiers are not needed?

Comment: RegExes are mostly used when you are not sure about the string you are looking for or a part of it. But I see you are doing a simple search, knowing the entire search term. I'm not a Ruby guy but it seems you are ok with [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) method. Although you may call it multiple times it should be much more faster. Cloistered pattern modifiers `(?-mix:` are not necessary since you are unsettling flags repeatedly that are off by default.

Comment: @revo Yes I know the include method, the include method will not work for this specific program. I have no idea why, but it doesn't work as expected lol. Regex seems to be the only thing that works here. Thank you for the info on `(?-mix:`

Comment: Then your RegEx is completely fine.

Comment: @revo Alright, post it as an answer and I'll accept it.\